# Component with React Suspense cause Eternal Loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-suspense

I am learning React, and trying to use Suspense.

On the First, I try to use wrapped promise object for props.
Wrapper throw promise when it not solved.  It loop forever.
Then I try it with useEffect, but it has same problem.

Here is my code and sandbox.
Please lecture me how to solve this problem.

[textsandbox  EternalLoop](https://codesandbox.io/s/eternal-loop-l24if)
* useEffect block comment outed in sandbox because it loops forever.

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const lazyTimer = () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(" from 10sec past");
    }, 1000);
  });
  return promise;
};

const wrapPromise = promise => {
  let status = "pending";
  let result;
  console.log("looping....");

  const suspender = promise.then(
    r => {
      status = "fulfilled";
      result = r;
    },
    e => {
      status = "rejected";
      result = e;
    }
  );
  const read = () => {
    if (status === "pending") {
      throw suspender;
    } else if (status === "rejected") {
      throw result;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  };
  return { read };
};

const Hallo = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("your on time");
  // useEffect(
  //   setText(
  //     wrapPromise(lazyTimer()).read()
  //   ), [text],
  // );
  return <h2>hello world, {text}</h2>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <Hallo />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 3: What has been confusing for me with suspense that I don't see documented is how it works. IE, how the children work. It appears to me that you throw a promise from looking at the demo's code in the documentation. But I don't see this documented anywhere.

So you throw a promise that when resolved your component is now ready (ie. the timer promise - or an Apollo Client promise - fetch promise, etc.).  When that promise resolves, your component can now mount. I love that, I wish it was documented clearly if I'm right on how it works.

---

This problem has nothing to do with suspense. Your code:

```
const Hallo = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("your on time");
  useEffect(
  //   setText(
  //     wrapPromise(lazyTimer()).read()
  //   ), [text],
  // );
  return <h2>hello world, {text}</h2>;
};
```

Has this problem. It runs `setText`, then it has `text` as a dependency. So you change `text`, then it runs again because `text` changes. Hence the infinite loop.

You have 3 ways to fix this

1) Do some `if` statement to make it not an infinite loop (ie. you know what text shouldn't be or check if it is the same).

2) Remove `text` from the dependency list (bad!)

3) remove it by using the alternative `setText` method, calling it as a function instead of providing a value. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for documentation.

```
   useEffect(
       setText(text => wrapPromise(lazyTimer()).read())
     ), [],
   );
```

then `text` will not be a dependency.

I recommend 3.

---

Edit:

On top of that, you were using the wrapper incorrectly. I looked at the [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-suspense-for-data-fetching/) you probably used and its [Github](https://github.com/ovieokeh/suspense-data-fetching/tree/master/lib). They create the wrapper. Then in the data fetching portion (your timer) wrap their promise in the promise wrapper.

I tried to keep your code as similar as possible using `useEffect`:

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const wrapPromise = promise => {
  let status = "pending";
  let result;
  console.log(`looping.... + ${new Date().toString()}`);

  const suspender = promise.then(
    r => {
      status = "fulfilled";
      result = r;
    },
    e => {
      status = "rejected";
      result = e;
    }
  );
  const read = () => {
    if (status === "pending") {
      throw suspender;
    } else if (status === "rejected") {
      throw result;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  };
  return { read };
};

const lazyTimer = () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(" from 10sec past");
    }, 10000);
  });
  return wrapPromise(promise);
};

const data = lazyTimer();

const Hallo = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(data.read());
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Im running");
    setText(data.read());
  }, []);

  return <h2>hello world, {text}</h2>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <Hallo />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This works. Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eternal-loop-35f6u?file=/src/App.js:0-1180).

Of note, halo could just be:

```
const Hallo = () => {
  const text = data.read()
  return <h2>hello world, {text}</h2>;
};
```

Comment: Hi, Diesel. Thanks for anser. also I love Diesel brand.
I tried your suggestion on sandbox. But still it loops.
Do I have other mistakes?
I fix sandbox with your suggestion.

Comment: Great Answer Diesel !  
I really appreciate your help.  
I try to study again how wrapper works in tutorial.  
My problem was perfectly solved.  
This is best answer.